# Character of $i$-th exterior power of a complex semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$

Tags: representation-theory, characters, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a complex semisimple Lie algebra. Denote $\bigwedge^i\mathfrak{g}$ the $i$-th exterior power of $\mathfrak{g}$. 
Define: 
$$\mathrm{ch}(V)=\sum_{\lambda\in\mathfrak{h}^*}(\dim V_\lambda) e(\lambda),$$

where $V_\lambda$ is the weight space corresponding to weight $\lambda$.

> I would like to know what is $\mathrm{ch}\left(\bigwedge^i\mathfrak{g}\right)$ for $0\le i\le n$? 
>   Is: 
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}\mathrm{ch}\left(\bigwedge^i\mathfrak{g}\right),$$ invertible?

Comment: For $\mathfrak{sl}_2$, we have the characters of $\wedge^0, \wedge^1, \wedge^2, \wedge^3$ of the adjoint representation are respectively $1, q^{-1} + 1 + q, q^{-1} + 1 + q, 1$. So their alternating sum is 0, which is not invertible.

Comment: I have heard that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-1)^{i}\mathrm{ch}\left(\wedge^i\mathfrak{g}\right)$ is related to Weyl's Denominator Formula and somehow it is invertible. You means what I heard is wrong?

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you.